# my computer shutdown before windows 7 logo

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, motherboard

what do i need to do here? my computer shutdowns before windows 7 logo appear.

i also tried a hard disk of a friend. but it keeps rebooting. it reboots before windows 7 appears. even starting using safe mode makes the computer reboot. when i select the repair my computer. it shows me that hard disk reading error. so what is the problem here? even the hard disk of a friend of my says "hard disk reading error" but the hard disk is readable on the bios.

Comment: Tried different SATA/IDE cable?

Comment: yes i used different cable. and im using SATA cable. the question here is why is it readable on my BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

When the  computer start ,Enter to the bios  setting , then go to hard drive options and check sata mode instead of ahci mode (or the inverse)

Answer (score 0):

"Readable on the BIOS" is a very loose phrase. The BIOS does not interact with a disk in the same way an operating system does. And even so, this probably isn't related to your issue.

At this point you should probably try ruling some things out so you can narrow down what the issue actually is. Try Booting a distro of linux from a USB to confirm that the rest of you computer actually works, and then use Gparted to examine and attempt a repair on your windows boot partition.

If you have a windows rescue disk or the original disk that you used to install Windows, often times they will have a "Startup Repair" feature that you can use to auto repair the boot sequence if that is where the error is occurring.